# Select rows of a matrix that meet a condition

Tags: r, select, matrix, submatrix

In R with a matrix:

```
     one two three four
 [1,]   1   6    11   16
 [2,]   2   7    12   17
 [3,]   3   8    11   18
 [4,]   4   9    11   19
 [5,]   5  10    15   20
```

I want to extract the submatrix whose rows have column three = 11. That is:

```
      one two three four
 [1,]   1   6    11   16
 [3,]   3   8    11   18
 [4,]   4   9    11   19
```

I want to do this without looping. I am new to R so this is probably very obvious but the
documentation is often somewhat terse.

Comment: The basic idea in every answer is that if you have a logical vector/matrix (TRUEs and FALSEs) of the same length as some index, you will select only the cases that are TRUE. Run the codes between `[ ]` in the answers and you will see this more clearly.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

This is easier to do if you convert your matrix to a data frame using as.data.frame().  In that case the previous answers (using subset or m$three) will work, otherwise they will not.

To perform the operation on a *matrix*, you can define a column by name:

```
m[m[, "three"] == 11,]
```

Or by number:

```
m[m[,3] == 11,]
```

Note that if only one row matches, the result is an integer vector, not a matrix.

Comment: if you need to keep the matrix, then do `m[m[,3] == 11,,drop=FALSE]`

Comment: @neilfws What will be the solution if I want to define some values for a range of columns. for example `df <- df[!which(df$ARID3A:df$YY1 == "U"),]`, here I want to remove those rows from my df where a range of columns (ARID3A: YY1) contains the value *U*.

Comment: How does this work if you don't want to specify the column names at all but want to work over all columns in the matrix?

Comment: Hey @neilfws , how can you add && statement to this one? I need to get two columns values at the same time?

Answer (score 34):

```
m <- matrix(1:20, ncol = 4) 
colnames(m) <- letters[1:4]
```

The following command will select the first row of the matrix above.

```
subset(m, m[,4] == 16)
```

And this will select the last three.

```
subset(m, m[,4] > 17)
```

The result will be a matrix in both cases.
If you want to use column names to select columns then you would be best off converting it to a dataframe with

```
mf <- data.frame(m)
```

Then you can select with

```
mf[ mf$a == 16, ]
```

Or, you could use the subset command.

Answer (score 34):

I will choose a simple approach using the dplyr package.

If the dataframe is data.

```
library(dplyr)
result <- filter(data, three == 11)
```

Answer (score 12):

Subset is a very slow function , and I personally find it useless.

I assume you have a data.frame, array, matrix called `Mat` with `A`, `B`, `C` as column names; then all you need to do is:

- In the case of one condition on one column, lets say column A

  ```
  Mat[which(Mat[,'A'] == 10), ]
  ```

In the case of multiple conditions on different column, you can create a dummy variable. Suppose the conditions are `A = 10`, `B = 5`, and `C > 2`, then we have:

```
    aux = which(Mat[,'A'] == 10)
    aux = aux[which(Mat[aux,'B'] == 5)]
    aux = aux[which(Mat[aux,'C'] > 2)]
    Mat[aux, ]
```

By testing the speed advantage with `system.time`, the `which` method is 10x faster than the `subset` method.

Answer (score 9):

If your matrix is called `m`, just use :

```
R> m[m$three == 11, ]
```

Comment: @juba What will be the solution if I want to define some values for a range of columns. for example `df <- df[!which(df$ARID3A:df$YY1 == "U"),]`, here I want to remove those rows from my df where a range of columns (ARID3A: YY1) contains the value `U`

Answer (score 0):

If the dataset is called data, then all the rows meeting a condition where value of column 'pm2.5' > 300 can be received by -

```
data[data['pm2.5'] >300,]
```