# Selecting only a specific number of rows fulfilling a condition

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

I currently started to work with octave for some data analysis and have some problems for a specific matrix manipulation.

Assume you have the following data matrix:

```
    A =

        1   11   22   33
       44   13   12   33
        1   14   33   44
```

Now I would like to delete all rows of this matrix which don't accomplish e.g. the following condition.

```
    octave:6> A(:, 4) == 33
    ans =

       1
       1
       0
```

And I'll get the matrix of this form which only selects these rows:

```
    A_new =

        1   11   22   33
       44   13   12   33
```

I know this is possible with the help of some loops. But is there maybe a cleaner solution e.g. by using the provided standard library? That would be great :]

Some similar question was also already posted for R:
[In R, select rows of a matrix that meet a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391124/in-r-select-rows-of-a-matrix-that-meet-a-condition)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Try:

```
A = [
    1   11   22   33
    44  13   12   33
    1   14   33   44
];
idx = ( A(:,4)==33 );
A_new = A(idx,:)
```

This is using [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1)