# In R, select row of a matrix that match a vector

Tags: r, matrix, vector

R beginner here, need ur help. Lets say we have a matrix like this one:

```
     1   2   3
1    1   0   0
2    0   1   0
3    0   0   1
4    1   1   0
5    1   0   1 
6    0   1   1
7    1   1   1
```

Next we have a certain vector f.e. (1, 0, 1), wich would be matching row 5.
Whats the best way to get the index 5 from the matrix given that vector? 
I have allready read the questions 
[R - fastest way to select the rows of a matrix that satisfy multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128516/r-fastest-way-to-select-the-rows-of-a-matrix-that-satisfy-multiple-conditions)
and
[In R, select rows of a matrix that meet a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391124/in-r-select-rows-of-a-matrix-that-meet-a-condition)
but i think the situation differs in this case. Thanx for your input!

Comment: Hi. Why do you think your situation differs? In my opinion, the links you post are good solutions for your problem. But maybe I'm missing something.  Could you clarify? Thanks.

Comment: @Imzcig Guess you are right, but i have the feeling that there must be a more elegant way of doing it, as my vectors and  the count of columns is quite large... For my example posted, they would certainly be good solutions.

Comment: can I check all rows where this pattern is matched 66% of the times

Answer (score 1):

I can propose combination of `which`, `apply`, and `all` functions.

```
m <- matrix(c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1), 7, byrow=TRUE)

which(apply(m, 1, function(x) return(all(x == c(1,0,1)))))

[1] 5
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rowSums`

```
which(rowSums(m1 == rep(c(1,0,1), each = nrow(m1)))==3)
#5 
#5
```