# Selecting rows where a value in one of a number of columns matches one of a separate vector/list in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, lookup

Similar to: [In R, select row of a matrix that match a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40437929/in-r-select-row-of-a-matrix-that-match-a-vector)

Dataframe:

```
structure(list(id = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
"20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", 
"31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", 
"42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50"), X1 = c(8L, 
18L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 12L, 20L, 19L, 17L, 6L, 20L, 3L, 14L, 20L, 
11L, 17L, 19L, 3L, 12L, 17L, 20L, 14L, 11L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
7L, 18L, 7L, 12L, 18L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 20L, 11L, 17L, 15L, 6L, 2L, 
17L, 14L, 15L, 10L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 3L), X2 = c(1L, 3L, 10L, 14L, 
12L, 9L, 0L, 1L, 7L, 14L, 3L, 10L, 5L, 15L, 1L, 14L, 17L, 9L, 
16L, 6L, 10L, 6L, 1L, 11L, 8L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 14L, 4L, 16L, 5L, 
15L, 11L, 10L, 0L, 16L, 16L, 15L, 20L, 5L, 1L, 9L, 2L, 16L, 12L, 
4L, 2L, 15L, 11L), X3 = c(16L, 2L, 10L, 19L, 5L, 16L, 13L, 14L, 
10L, 15L, 18L, 17L, 0L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 19L, 3L, 2L, 20L, 19L, 14L, 
18L, 13L, 5L, 15L, 13L, 6L, 9L, 17L, 9L, 17L, 15L, 1L, 20L, 17L, 
19L, 13L, 15L, 4L, 9L, 0L, 13L, 9L, 11L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 5L, 16L), 
    X4 = c(14L, 16L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 13L, 5L, 9L, 16L, 15L, 
    3L, 11L, 8L, 2L, 17L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 18L, 0L, 14L, 18L, 19L, 
    6L, 17L, 15L, 11L, 19L, 13L, 2L, 12L, 8L, 4L, 17L, 14L, 9L, 
    18L, 10L, 19L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 7L, 16L, 2L, 19L, 12L, 
    13L), X5 = c(8L, 7L, 18L, 20L, 9L, 12L, 4L, 5L, 18L, 14L, 
    10L, 3L, 8L, 9L, 15L, 13L, 2L, 3L, 18L, 7L, 16L, 17L, 20L, 
    15L, 9L, 17L, 9L, 17L, 14L, 10L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 2L, 13L, 20L, 
    16L, 12L, 14L, 20L, 1L, 9L, 8L, 14L, 19L, 12L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 
    5L), X6 = c(10L, 2L, 11L, 19L, 2L, 11L, 7L, 12L, 16L, 17L, 
    2L, 9L, 20L, 0L, 19L, 1L, 15L, 15L, 6L, 8L, 1L, 15L, 11L, 
    17L, 16L, 8L, 16L, 20L, 15L, 9L, 7L, 15L, 12L, 14L, 20L, 
    4L, 12L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 13L, 17L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 17L, 0L, 19L, 
    19L, 14L), X7 = c(13L, 19L, 12L, 14L, 17L, 14L, 18L, 12L, 
    7L, 1L, 10L, 14L, 20L, 11L, 20L, 12L, 15L, 2L, 11L, 20L, 
    1L, 3L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 18L, 8L, 13L, 14L, 8L, 6L, 
    11L, 8L, 10L, 3L, 10L, 4L, 5L, 15L, 11L, 12L, 16L, 11L, 8L, 
    3L, 8L, 9L, 1L), X8 = c(7L, 17L, 7L, 17L, 17L, 6L, 18L, 11L, 
    14L, 17L, 1L, 4L, 18L, 9L, 15L, 20L, 12L, 8L, 5L, 20L, 6L, 
    15L, 8L, 3L, 12L, 1L, 14L, 12L, 6L, 0L, 8L, 13L, 20L, 0L, 
    20L, 20L, 13L, 9L, 0L, 17L, 1L, 2L, 15L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 20L, 
    11L, 15L, 11L), X9 = c(17L, 6L, 16L, 13L, 15L, 3L, 12L, 15L, 
    7L, 15L, 1L, 1L, 17L, 17L, 13L, 4L, 11L, 10L, 19L, 6L, 11L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 4L, 5L, 17L, 8L, 12L, 16L, 12L, 
    20L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 16L, 8L, 20L, 0L, 15L, 9L, 2L, 6L, 19L, 
    7L, 11L, 7L), X10 = c(15L, 11L, 4L, 1L, 10L, 18L, 16L, 2L, 
    1L, 0L, 9L, 19L, 1L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 14L, 15L, 8L, 12L, 12L, 
    20L, 13L, 13L, 3L, 13L, 8L, 4L, 19L, 3L, 0L, 15L, 18L, 15L, 
    19L, 13L, 15L, 18L, 8L, 9L, 17L, 2L, 1L, 18L, 5L, 19L, 10L, 
    16L, 5L, 12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -50L
))
```

I want to select the rows where any one of `x1`-`x10` equals any one of a vector `x <-c(0:5)`. In reality `x1`-`x10` has many `NA`s and the vector contains entries that are made up of letters and numbers e.g `X1425`, `52546`, `HPO1567` etc.

I know about the `%in%` sign but if I wanted this to apply to multiple columns and for it to return the row if only a single vector matches only a single row what would be the best way of doing that?

My expected outcome is the whole row as it appears in the original table where any column matches any of the search vector how every many times e.g. multiple matches in the same row.

Ideally in base R.

Many thanks

Comment: does the row have to contain ONLY a single member of the vector `x`, or can it have multiple matches? At the end, are you looking for a vector of matching row numbers, a logical vector of TRUE/FALSE for each row, or the rows themselves (i.e. a subset of the data frame)?

Comment: @AllanCameron I've updated my question: My expected outcome is the whole row as it appears in the original table where any column matches any of the search vector how every many times e.g. multiple matches in the same row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a slightly different approach from @Duck using `any` instead of `sum` , so you don't need to use a filter afterwards:

```
vec= c(2,20)
rows = apply(data1[,-1],1,function(x) any(x %in% vec))
data1[rows,]

   id X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
2   2 18  3  2 16  7  2 19 17  6  11
4   4 10 14 19  2 20 19 14 17 13   1
5   5  2 12  5  2  9  2 17 17 15  10
7   7 20  0 13 13  4  7 18 18 12  16
8   8 19  1 14  5  5 12 12 11 15   2
11 11 20  3 18 15 10  2 10  1  1   9
13 13 14  5  0 11  8 20 20 18 17   1
14 14 20 15  2  8  9  0 11  9 17  11
15 15 11  1  7  2 15 19 20 15 13   0
16 16 17 14  5 17 13  1 12 20  4   0
17 17 19 17 19  1  2 15 15 12 11  14
18 18  3  9  3  1  3 15  2  8 10  15
19 19 12 16  2  5 18  6 11  5 19   8
20 20 17  6 20 18  7  8 20 20  6  12
21 21 20 10 19  0 16  1  1  6 11  12
22 22 14  6 14 14 17 15  3 15  3  20
23 23 11  1 18 18 20 11 10  8  3  13
27 27  2  0 13 15  9 16 15 14 12   8
28 28  4  3  6 11 17 20 18 12  4   4
31 31  7 16  9  2  4  7 14  8  8   0
33 33 18 15 15  8  0 12  6 20 16  18
34 34  6 11  1  4  2 14 11  0 12  15
35 35  6 10 20 17 13 20  8 20 20  19
36 36  6  0 17 14 20  4 10 20  3  13
37 37 20 16 19  9 16 12  3 13  5  15
39 39 17 15 15 10 14  2  4  0 16   8
40 40 15 20  4 19 20  5  5 17  8   9
41 41  6  5  9 14  1 13 15  1 20  17
42 42  2  1  0 14  9 17 11  2  0   2
43 43 17  9 13 15  8  2 12 15 15   1
44 44 14  2  9 15 14  2 16 10  9  18
45 45 15 16 11  7 19  2 11  2  2   5
46 46 10 12  2 16 12 17  8  1  6  19
47 47  4  4  0  2  2  0  3 20 19  10
48 48  4  2  5 19  0 19  8 11  7  16
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, and then filter by `Index`

```
vec <-c(0:5)
Data$Index <- apply(Data[,-1],1,function(x) sum(x %in% vec))

   id X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 Index
1   1  8  1 16 14  8 10 13  7 17  15     1
2   2 18  3  2 16  7  2 19 17  6  11     3
3   3  6 10 10  6 18 11 12  7 16   4     1
4   4 10 14 19  2 20 19 14 17 13   1     2
5   5  2 12  5  2  9  2 17 17 15  10     4
6   6 12  9 16 10 12 11 14  6  3  18     1
7   7 20  0 13 13  4  7 18 18 12  16     2
8   8 19  1 14  5  5 12 12 11 15   2     4
9   9 17  7 10  9 18 16  7 14  7   1     1
10 10  6 14 15 16 14 17  1 17 15   0     2
11 11 20  3 18 15 10  2 10  1  1   9     4
12 12  3 10 17  3  3  9 14  4  1  19     5
13 13 14  5  0 11  8 20 20 18 17   1     3
14 14 20 15  2  8  9  0 11  9 17  11     2
15 15 11  1  7  2 15 19 20 15 13   0     3
16 16 17 14  5 17 13  1 12 20  4   0     4
17 17 19 17 19  1  2 15 15 12 11  14     2
18 18  3  9  3  1  3 15  2  8 10  15     5
19 19 12 16  2  5 18  6 11  5 19   8     3
20 20 17  6 20 18  7  8 20 20  6  12     0
21 21 20 10 19  0 16  1  1  6 11  12     3
22 22 14  6 14 14 17 15  3 15  3  20     2
23 23 11  1 18 18 20 11 10  8  3  13     2
24 24  1 11 13 19 15 17 11  3  3  13     3
25 25  9  8  5  6  9 16 12 12  9   3     2
26 26  1  1 15 17 17  8 13  1 10  13     3
27 27  2  0 13 15  9 16 15 14 12   8     2
28 28  4  3  6 11 17 20 18 12  4   4     4
29 29  7 14  9 19 14 15  8  6  5  19     1
30 30 18  4 17 13 10  9 13  0 17   3     3
31 31  7 16  9  2  4  7 14  8  8   0     3
32 32 12  5 17 12  5 15  8 13 12  15     2
33 33 18 15 15  8  0 12  6 20 16  18     1
34 34  6 11  1  4  2 14 11  0 12  15     4
35 35  6 10 20 17 13 20  8 20 20  19     0
36 36  6  0 17 14 20  4 10 20  3  13     3
37 37 20 16 19  9 16 12  3 13  5  15     2
38 38 11 16 13 18 12  6 10  9  6  18     0
39 39 17 15 15 10 14  2  4  0 16   8     3
40 40 15 20  4 19 20  5  5 17  8   9     3
41 41  6  5  9 14  1 13 15  1 20  17     3
42 42  2  1  0 14  9 17 11  2  0   2     6
43 43 17  9 13 15  8  2 12 15 15   1     2
44 44 14  2  9 15 14  2 16 10  9  18     2
45 45 15 16 11  7 19  2 11  2  2   5     4
46 46 10 12  2 16 12 17  8  1  6  19     2
47 47  4  4  0  2  2  0  3 20 19  10     7
48 48  4  2  5 19  0 19  8 11  7  16     4
49 49  7 15  5 12  1 19  9 15 11   5     3
50 50  3 11 16 13  5 14  1 11  7  12     3
```

`Data` is your `dput()` data. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a (fun) regex solution:

It works by first `paste0`ing all rows into strings and then, using `grepl`, matching the numbers from `0-5` in these rows to finally subset the dataframe `df` on those rows for `which` matches are returned:

```
df[which(grepl("(?<=^| )[0-5](?= |$)", apply(df[-1], 1, paste0, collapse = " "), perl = T)),]
   id X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1   1  8  1 16 14  8 10 13  7 17  15
2   2 18  3  2 16  7  2 19 17  6  11
3   3  6 10 10  6 18 11 12  7 16   4
4   4 10 14 19  2 20 19 14 17 13   1
5   5  2 12  5  2  9  2 17 17 15  10
6   6 12  9 16 10 12 11 14  6  3  18
7   7 20  0 13 13  4  7 18 18 12  16
8   8 19  1 14  5  5 12 12 11 15   2
9   9 17  7 10  9 18 16  7 14  7   1
10 10  6 14 15 16 14 17  1 17 15   0
11 11 20  3 18 15 10  2 10  1  1   9
12 12  3 10 17  3  3  9 14  4  1  19
13 13 14  5  0 11  8 20 20 18 17   1
14 14 20 15  2  8  9  0 11  9 17  11
15 15 11  1  7  2 15 19 20 15 13   0
16 16 17 14  5 17 13  1 12 20  4   0
17 17 19 17 19  1  2 15 15 12 11  14
18 18  3  9  3  1  3 15  2  8 10  15
19 19 12 16  2  5 18  6 11  5 19   8
21 21 20 10 19  0 16  1  1  6 11  12
22 22 14  6 14 14 17 15  3 15  3  20
23 23 11  1 18 18 20 11 10  8  3  13
24 24  1 11 13 19 15 17 11  3  3  13
25 25  9  8  5  6  9 16 12 12  9   3
26 26  1  1 15 17 17  8 13  1 10  13
27 27  2  0 13 15  9 16 15 14 12   8
28 28  4  3  6 11 17 20 18 12  4   4
29 29  7 14  9 19 14 15  8  6  5  19
30 30 18  4 17 13 10  9 13  0 17   3
31 31  7 16  9  2  4  7 14  8  8   0
32 32 12  5 17 12  5 15  8 13 12  15
33 33 18 15 15  8  0 12  6 20 16  18
34 34  6 11  1  4  2 14 11  0 12  15
36 36  6  0 17 14 20  4 10 20  3  13
37 37 20 16 19  9 16 12  3 13  5  15
39 39 17 15 15 10 14  2  4  0 16   8
40 40 15 20  4 19 20  5  5 17  8   9
41 41  6  5  9 14  1 13 15  1 20  17
42 42  2  1  0 14  9 17 11  2  0   2
43 43 17  9 13 15  8  2 12 15 15   1
44 44 14  2  9 15 14  2 16 10  9  18
45 45 15 16 11  7 19  2 11  2  2   5
46 46 10 12  2 16 12 17  8  1  6  19
47 47  4  4  0  2  2  0  3 20 19  10
48 48  4  2  5 19  0 19  8 11  7  16
49 49  7 15  5 12  1 19  9 15 11   5
50 50  3 11 16 13  5 14  1 11  7  12
```