# Merge rows with condition and limit in a dataframe

Tags: r, matrix, merge, dataframe, plyr

I have the following dummy dataset of 1000 observations:

```
obs <- 1000

df <- data.frame(
  a=c(1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0),
  b=c(0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0),
  c=c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0),
  d=c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0),
  e=c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1),
  f=c(10,2,4,5,2,2,1,2,1,4),
  g=sample(c("yes", "no"), obs, replace = TRUE),
  h=sample(letters[1:15], obs, replace = TRUE),
  i=sample(c("VF","FD", "VD"), obs, replace = TRUE),
  j=sample(1:10, obs, replace = TRUE)
)
```

One key feature of this dataset is that the variables `a` to `e`'s values are only one `1` and the rest are `0`. We are sure the only one of these five columns have a `1` as value.

I found [a way to extract these rows given a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5391697/1685185) (with a `1`) and assign to their respective variables:

```
df.a <- df[df[,"a"] == 1,,drop=FALSE]
df.b <- df[df[,"b"] == 1,,drop=FALSE]
df.c <- df[df[,"c"] == 1,,drop=FALSE]
df.d <- df[df[,"d"] == 1,,drop=FALSE]
df.e <- df[df[,"e"] == 1,,drop=FALSE]
```

My dilemma now is to limit the rows saved into `df.a` to `df.e` and to merge them afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a shorter way to create `df.merged`:

```
# variables of 'df'
vars <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")

# number of rows to extract
n <- 100

df.merged <- do.call(rbind, lapply(vars, function(x) {
  head(df[as.logical(df[[x]]), ], n)
}))
```

Here, `rbind` is sufficient. The function `rbind.fill` is necessary if your data frames differ with respect to the number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

1. To get the *n*-rows subset, a simple `data[1:n,]` does the job.

   ```
   df.a.sub <- df.a[1:10,]
   df.b.sub <- df.b[1:10,]
   df.c.sub <- df.c[1:10,]
   df.d.sub <- df.d[1:10,]
   df.e.sub <- df.e[1:10,]
   ```
2. Finally, merge them by (it took the most time to find a straightforward "merge multiple dataframes" and all I needed to do was `rbind.fill(df1, df2, ..., dfn)` thanks to [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2851434/1685185)):

   ```
   require(plyr)
   df.merged <- rbind.fill(df.a.sub, df.b.sub, df.c.sub, df.d.sub, df.e.sub)
   ```